# Sending email using jenkins getting following error response

Tags: java, email, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Here I mention the email stage 
def subject = "Job ${buildStatus} - ${env.JOB_NAME} - Build

```
${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
        echo "env variable running"
        echo "${subject}"
        def summary = "${subject}"
        echo "${summary}"
        def details = """ Your Job's build has been ${buildStatus}. Click the URL to view the build log. \n\n ${env.BUILD_URL} \n\n Sent from JustOps.io"""
        echo "${details}"

         mail to: "rajesh@cogzidel.com",
         subject: "${summary}",
         body: "${details}"
```

I am getting following error
Error when executing success post condition:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
    javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_755_422232966.1533023412891"
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1141)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MailStep$MailStepExecution.run(MailStep.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MailStep$MailStepExecution.run(MailStep.java:128)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:50)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_755_422232966.1533023412891"
    at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:896)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:317)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1476)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1772)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1099)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to underlying JavaMail not configured for mime types.
An html handler is provided in JavaMail 1.1.3 but the mailcap file is not configured for this. Try adding the below line -

```
text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html
```

Comment: thanks @mdero .where i add this line in jenkins declarative pipe line script.

Answer (score 1):

in a scripted pipeline you would do something like this

```
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
import javax.activation.CommandMap;

@NonCPS
def setupMail(){
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content- handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
}

node {
    setupMail()
    mail(   from: 'jenkins@co.com', 
            replyTo: 'me@co.com', 
            to: someone@co.com,
            subject: "Hi there MIME",  
            body: "It Works!")
}
```

Bug is tracked here https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-53305